# Rails Query - popular but not sold out events

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I have en example of an app in which I have `Events`, each event has many `Ticket types` (like Basic, VIP), and many `Tickets`.

The price of the ticket is on the `ticket type`, if a `ticket` has been purchased the `ticket.state` is set to `purchased`, if it's not it stays `empty`.

The problem that I'm having is that I want to display top 10 of popular `Events`, which means, those events that have the highest number of ticket purchased but they must not be sold out, meaning, `Event.tickets` should also contain some with an empty status.

The questions is, how can I write an Rails Query, that will give me the top 10, ordered desc by purchased tickets, and at the same time that events must have at least one ticket with an empty state.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ticket_types
    has_many :tickets, through: :ticket_types
end

class TicketType < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event, touch: true
   has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket_type, touch: true
  has_one :event, through: :ticket_type
end
```

Comment: Im sure there is a way to do this with one query and many subqueries. I would add a cached_column on Event called remaining_tickets and update it every time a ticket is marked as sold. Then you could just sort event by remaining_tickets ASC.